# @NotNull, @Email annotation not working

Tags: validation, spring-mvc

im trying some of the validation capabilities of spring MVC but i just cant make @NotNull and @Email work, @Size is working pretty well, but it seem the other 2 just doesnt report errors at the bindingresult.
could anyone give an idea.

```
package com.carloscortina.paidos.model;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringBuilder;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Email;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.ScriptAssert;

@ScriptAssert(lang="javascript",
         script="_this.confirmPassword.equals(_this.password)",
         message = "personal.password.mismatch.message")
public class PersonalRegistryForm {

private Long id;
private String pNombre,sNombre,apellidoP,apellidoM,
    username,password,confirmPassword,email,telCel,telefono,categoria;
boolean acceptTerms=true;

/**
 * @return the id
 */
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
/**
 * @param id the id to set
 */
public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
/**
 * @return the pNombre
 */
public String getpNombre() {
    return pNombre;
}
/**
 * @param pNombre the pNombre to set
 */
public void setpNombre(String pNombre) {
    this.pNombre = pNombre;
}
/**
 * @return the sNombre
 */
public String getsNombre() {
    return sNombre;
}
/**
 * @param sNombre the sNombre to set
 */
public void setsNombre(String sNombre) {
    this.sNombre = sNombre;
}
/**
 * @return the apellidoP
 */
public String getApellidoP() {
    return apellidoP;
}
/**
 * @param apellidoP the apellidoP to set
 */
public void setApellidoP(String apellidoP) {
    this.apellidoP = apellidoP;
}
/**
 * @return the apellidoM
 */
public String getApellidoM() {
    return apellidoM;
}
/**
 * @param apellidoM the apellidoM to set
 */
public void setApellidoM(String apellidoM) {
    this.apellidoM = apellidoM;
}
/**
 * @return the username
 */
@NotNull
@Size(min=4,max=12)
public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}
/**
 * @param username the username to set
 */
public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}
/**
 * @return the password
 */
@NotNull
@Size(min=8,max=12)
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
/**
 * @param password the password to set
 */
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
/**
 * @return the confirmPassword
 */
@NotNull
public String getConfirmPassword() {
    return confirmPassword;
}
/**
 * @param confirmPassword the confirmPassword to set
 */
public void setConfirmPassword(String confirmPassword) {
    this.confirmPassword = confirmPassword;
}
/**
 * @return the email
 */
@NotNull
@Email
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
/**
 * @param email the email to set
 */
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
/**
 * @return the telCel
 */
public String getTelCel() {
    return telCel;
}
/**
 * @param telCel the telCel to set
 */
public void setTelCel(String telCel) {
    this.telCel = telCel;
}
/**
 * @return the telefono
 */
public String getTelefono() {
    return telefono;
}
/**
 * @param telefono the telefono to set
 */
public void setTelefono(String telefono) {
    this.telefono = telefono;
}
/**
 * @return the categoria
 */
public String getCategoria() {
    return categoria;
}
/**
 * @param categoria the categoria to set
 */
public void setCategoria(String categoria) {
    this.categoria = categoria;
}
/**
 * @return the acceptTerms
 */
public boolean isAcceptTerms() {
    return acceptTerms;
}
/**
 * @param acceptTerms the acceptTerms to set
 */
public void setAcceptTerms(boolean acceptTerms) {
    this.acceptTerms = acceptTerms;
}
/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
 */
@Override
public String toString() {
    ToStringBuilder builder = new ToStringBuilder(this);
    builder.append("id", id);
    builder.append("pNombre", pNombre);
    builder.append("sNombre", sNombre);
    builder.append("apellidoP", apellidoP);
    builder.append("apellidoM", apellidoM);
    builder.append("username", username);
    builder.append("password", password);
    builder.append("confirmPassword", confirmPassword);
    builder.append("email", email);
    builder.append("telCel", telCel);
    builder.append("telefono", telefono);
    builder.append("categoria", categoria);
    builder.append("acceptTerms", acceptTerms);
    return builder.toString();
}
}
```

The Controller

```
package com.carloscortina.paidos;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.WebDataBinder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.InitBinder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.carloscortina.paidos.model.PersonalRegistryForm;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/personal")
public class PersonalController {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PersonalController.class);
private final static String regForm="personal/RegistryForm";
private final static String regSubmit="redirect:RegistrySubmit"; 

@RequestMapping(value="new",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String getPersonalRegistrationForm(Model model){
    logger.info("desplegando forma");
    PersonalRegistryForm form = new PersonalRegistryForm() ;
    model.addAttribute("personalRegForm",form);
    return regForm;
}

@RequestMapping(value="",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String submitPersonalRegistrationForm(@ModelAttribute("personalRegForm") @Valid PersonalRegistryForm form,
            BindingResult result){

    //convertPasswordError(result);
    logger.info("Errores -->"+result.toString());
    return (result.hasErrors() ? regForm: regSubmit);
}

@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder){
    binder.setAllowedFields(new String[]{
        "username","password","confirmPassword","pNombre",
        "sNombre","apellidoP","apellidoM","email","telefono",
        "telCel","categoria","acceptTerms"});
}
}
```

The JSP

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>

<spring:message var="pageTitle" code="newUserRegistration.pageTitle" />
<spring:message var="allFields" code="newUserRegistration.message.allFieldsRequired" />
<spring:message var="username" code="newUserRegistration.label.username" />
<spring:message var="password" code="newUserRegistration.label.password" />
<spring:message var="confirmPassword" code="newUserRegistration.label.confirmPassword" />
<spring:message var="email" code="newUserRegistration.label.email" />
<spring:message var="firstName" code="newUserRegistration.label.pnombre" />
<spring:message var="secondName" code="newUserRegistration.label.snombre" />
<spring:message var="lastName" code="newUserRegistration.label.apellidop" />
<spring:message var="lastName1" code="newUserRegistration.label.apellidom" />
<spring:message var="telephone" code="newUserRegistration.label.telefono" />
<spring:message var="cellphone" code="newUserRegistration.label.celular" />
<spring:message var="category" code="newUserRegistration.label.categoria" />
<spring:message var="acceptTerms" code="newUserRegistration.label.terms" />
<spring:message var="submit" code="newUserRegistration.label.registrar" />

<head>
<title>${pageTitle}</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <form:form action="." modelAttribute="personalRegForm">
        <h1>${pageTitle}</h1>
        <form:errors path="*">
            <div><spring:message code="error.global" /></div>
        </form:errors>
        <div>
            ${username}
            <form:input path="username"/>
            <form:errors path="username">
                <div><form:errors path="username" htmlEscape="false" /></div>
            </form:errors>
        </div>
        <div>
            ${password}
            <form:password path="password"/>
            <form:errors path="password">
                <div><form:errors path="password" htmlEscape="false" /></div>
            </form:errors>
        </div>
        <div>
            ${confirmPassword}
            <form:password path="confirmPassword"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            ${email}
            <form:input path="email"/>
            <form:errors>
                <div><form:errors path="email" htmlEscape="false"/></div>
            </form:errors>
        </div>
        <div>
            ${firstName}
            <form:input path="pNombre"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            ${secondName}
            <form:input path="sNombre"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            ${lastName}
            <form:input path="ApellidoP"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            ${lastName1}
            <form:input path="ApellidoM"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            ${telephone}
            <form:input path="telefono"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            ${cellphone}
            <form:input path="telCel"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            ${category}
            <form:input path="categoria"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <form:checkbox path="acceptTerms"/>
            ${acceptTerms}
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="${submit}"/>
        </div>
    </form:form>    
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 5):

It seem it was my misunderstanding of the terms and capabilities of the validations.
@NotNull and @Email are indeed both working but not as i imagined.
@NotNull is for validating Null not empty and that was my misunderstanding and similarly @Email cant do the validation on empty strings.

well thanks to everyone that reads this and i hope this can help someone. it might be too noob but its good to learn.

Comment: Check out hibernate validator's @NotEmpty

Comment: Check out @NotBlank too